# Does react native support box-shadow parameter spread radius?

Tags: react-native

[Wiki](https://reactnative.dev/docs/shadow-props#reference) only refer to: shadowColor(color), shadowOffset(object), shadowOpacity(number) and shadowRadius(number). It is possible to use spread radius or this attribute is not suported?

```css
body {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

div {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<div/>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use `box-shadow` and, react native doesn't support any equivalent to *spread radius* css parameter.

`box-shadow: 0 0 16px 0 #666` represents :

`box-shadow: [horizontal offset] [vertical offset] [blur radius] [optional spread radius] [color];`

so, what you'll have to do is :

```
container: {
    backgroundColor:'white',
    padding: 24,
    margin:15,
    borderRadius: 8,
    borderColor: '#33CC99',
    borderWidth: 1,
    ...Platform.select({
     ios: {
       shadowColor: "#000",
       shadowOffset: {
         width: 0,
         height: 5,
       },
       shadowOpacity: 0.36,
       shadowRadius: 6.68,
     },
     android: {
       elevation: 11,
     },
    })
},
```

only `shadow*` in iOS and `elevation` in android,

[here](https://ethercreative.github.io/react-native-shadow-generator/) is a shadow generator for both os.

Comment: What i'm asking is if react native support an equivalent of *spread radius* witch is an parameter of css' box-shadow

Comment: Ok then react native doesn't support any equivalent to *spread radius* css parameter. I will update my answer with an example from one other stack-overflow question.